# MPDF Sum only the results per page

Tags: php, mysql, mpdf

I would like if its possible to show the sum of the records get it from database but from only per page.

So i insert all values into database and show it at the mpdf page and at the last page i show the total from all values into database but i would like to show per page the sum of the records only showed per page. I guess its kinda impossible, i seriously dont know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Page1:
value1
value2
total_page1

Page2:
value1
value2
value3
total_page2

PS: The values are from database.

Cumps.

Comment: Hi, could you please share some code to show what you've tried so far? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish something like that in SQL, you need to use aggregation. For example, a count of results per page might look something like this:

```
SELECT page_number, COUNT(*) AS numResults
FROM myTable
GROUP BY page_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **{colsum}**. It will automatically add sum on every page in the table. It's on http://mpdf1.com/examples/mpdf54demo.pdf.

You can read the code in example file included in downloaded library examples/example58_new_mPDF_v5-4_features.php

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header Row</th>
        <th>Header Row</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>Column total: (using colsum2 in {})</td>
        <td>{colsum2}</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>167.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>444.53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>14.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>0.88</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>144.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 6</td>
        <td>8089.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 7</td>
        <td>3.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 8</td>
        <td>23.00</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to place `<tfoot>` before `<tbody>`.